# Concept of Program Making Own Class Instances

Tags: conceptual

This is probably a basic question with a simple answer, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around the logic behind it.

I will start with a simple example with a well-known Java game, Minecraft. A player is put into a world and is allowed to interact with different objects. Say the player wants wood. He sees a tree, walks over, and cuts it down. He sees another tree, walks over, and does the same. He can do this as many times as he wants, and the game will load in more trees if the player explores far enough. But how is this done? In other words, how can a program make an essentially endless amount of trees that the player will always be able to interact with?

I imagine there is a tree class in the code. But obviously, the programmer has not coded in different class instances, such as tree1, tree2, and so on, since he has no idea how many trees will need to be loaded in the game. So how does the program do this without being told how many trees there will be?

In other words, I do not understand how programs can decide on their own to make x number of class instances instead of the programmer having to manually code his/her own class instances. How do game developers and other programmers do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is how would you do it?

Comment: Look at dynamically allocated arrays and the factory pattern.

Comment: @ryantxr an array that the program can add on to when needed possibly?

Comment: @Dai will do, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider how we might generate a random game map. Let's say the environment of the map will be in a forest. What sorts of objects are part of a forest?

1. Trees
2. Critters (i.e. squirrels, rabbits)
3. Forest floor texture (i.e. grass or fallen leaves)

We start with a basic 100x100 unit game map. We will have the program generate a number of trees between 10 and 30, and also generate the tree's X and Y coordinates with the condition that no tree can have the same X and Y coordinates. We do the same for the other objects.

Now we tell the program to load the game map with all of these objects in place. Done.

Comment: I realize that this option is perfectly viable, but I was thinking more in terms of a program without a unit map or grid

Comment: The concept is the same as a unit map except the mapping is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple grid where each position on the grid can be occupied
by an object. The object could be a tree, rock, or creature.
In this world, I have areas on the map defined as 'growable'.
In these areas, something will grow if there isn't something there already.
The game would have a set of turns. During each turn, I run a routine to 
find all the growable spots, and if there isn't something growing there
randomly determine if something should sprout. This way if someone
chops down a tree, that spot can sprout a new tree later in the game.

Perhaps the game is more complex and a simple grid isn't good enough.
Whatever the case, the game has to track all the objects in some way.